# Escape a dollar sign in string interpolation

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

How do I escape a dollar sign in string interpolation?

```
def getCompanion(name: String) = Class.forName(s"my.package.$name\$")

// --> "error: unclosed string literal"
```

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Just double it

```
scala> val name = "foo"
name: String = foo

scala> s"my.package.$name$$"
res0: String = my.package.foo$
```

Comment: Would love to see a link to some documentation on this one. There might be other cases than the exact one here, and the answer could then help more people

Comment: I can not find anything about this in the documentation. There is a PR to add it though: https://github.com/scala/docs.scala-lang/pull/1531

Comment: The documentation is now here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html#the-s-string-interpolator Nor sure what other cases there are?

Comment: I can confirm this works for the percentage sign (`%`) as well, because it breaks if used after a numerical value in the f-string.