# Escape string interpolation in anorm

Tags: scala, anorm

I want to insert the literal `'${a}'` into a table using anorm 2.5.2, which means I want to execute the bare SQL query

```
INSERT INTO `db`.`table` (`a`) VALUES ('${a}');
```

without using any anorm / string interpolation. When I try to do the following

```
SQL("INSERT INTO `db`.`table` (`a`) VALUES ('${a}');").execute()
```

I get an `anorm.Sql$MissingParameter: Missing parameter value` exception because it tries to use anorm interpolation on `${a}` but no value `a` is available in the scope.

How to escape the anorm / string interpolations `$...` and `${...}`?

[Escape a dollar sign in string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875530/escape-a-dollar-sign-in-string-interpolation) doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: The string is not a String Interpolation, so you don't need to escape the `$` in the first place. The problem is not caused by String Interpolation.

Comment: I should have said anorm interpolation, or whatever you want to call it, to make it more obvious what I mean. Yes, I know it does not use Scala's string interpolation internally, since then the $$ escape should work, which it doesn't. I'll change the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `${a}` the value of a parameter, i.e.

```
SQL("""INSERT INTO db.table (a) VALUES ({x})""").on("x" -> s"$${a}")
```

(`s"$${a}"` is the way to write `"${a}"` without getting a warning about possible missing interpolators).

The same can be written equivalently as

```
val lit = s"$${a}"
SQL"""INSERT INTO db.table (a) VALUES ($lit)"""
```

The below will *probably* work, but I am not sure:

```
SQL"INSERT INTO db.table (a) VALUES ('$${a}')"
```

It may also be worth asking if it's intentional behavior or a bug: when talking about parametrized SQL queries, it doesn't make sense to have a parameter *inside* `'`.

Comment: A value in the SQL parameters should never be passed using plain string interpolation or `#$` with Anorm interpolation, otherwise it introduces SQL injection risk.

Comment: @cchantep But it isn't a parameter according to the question.

Comment: Using it in `VALUES` means it is

Comment: @cchantep I don't agree (so far as it's an actual literal and not dynamically constructed), but on further thought `#$` is too large a hammer for this. I've rewritten the answer.

Comment: As long as a value is given to be updated or inserted in a column, that's a parameter, and so not setting it appropriately keep the risk of SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks, you actually understood my question. Unfortunately I cannot upvote you since I don't have 15 reputation. Yes, setting a string like `val a = "${a}"` and then using anorm interpolation or `.on("a" -> a)` would work, but is not quite nice, since I actually need this quite often. Escaping with `$$` unfortunately doesn't work like I wrote in the last sentence of my question. Yes, I was also wondering if it is intentional that you don't seem to be able to escape the dollar sign or not.

Comment: Note that in last solution I use Anorm's string interpolator: `SQL"..."`, not `SQL("...")`. It isn't clear from your last sentence whether you've tried `$$` in this case.

Comment: (Whether it'll actually work depends on details of Anorm's implementation.)

Comment: You are right, `SQL"..."` actually supports escaping, meaning they behave differently. You can also use `SQL"#$query"` to insert a whole bare SQL query, which also doesn't work with `SQL("#$query")`. I don't believe any of this is intentional, it appears quite arbitrary. As a matter of fact, the documentation doesn't mention anything about `SQL("...")` supporting any kind of string interpolation by itself.

Comment: It's quite intentional. `SQL(...)` is just a method, it doesn't do any string interpolation (of course, you can write something like `SQL(s"$cmd * FROM $table ..."`, but you _should_ be careful not to use normal string interpolation for parameters). It just happens to search for `{...}` inside this string and convert it to a prepared statement parameter. This is also why `#$` makes no sense for it.