# scala string interpolation for "$"

Tags: scala, string-interpolation, scala-repl

Why does string interpolation not work when the name of value of '$'?

In the following code, why does the value of $ not get printed? What is the mistake when the value of x is printed using string interpolation?

```scala
repl> val x="test value"
repl> val $="some value"
repl> println($)
some value
repl> println(s"value:$x")
value:test value
repl> println(s"value:$$")
value:$
```

Why is the $ not replaced by its value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To actually print the value of the variable represented by `$`, you should enclose it in braces:

```
println(s"value:${$}")
```

outputs:

```
value:some value
```

Doubling the `$` sign does not work because it is used to escape $ itself as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16875626/2928853).